# UITableView Section condition not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a very strange problem in my table view.
I am using different sections for table view and each section has different number of rows. I have some text fields in the cells of table view. The problem is that when I scroll the table view down the first cell of first section's text field and the last section first row text fields overlap on one another. And the same thing happens when I scroll up the table view.

```
static NSString *cellIdetifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdetifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:cellIdetifier];
    }
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            titleAdded = 1;
            self.nameView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.eventName.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [cell addSubview:self.nameView];
        }
        else if (indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"in section 0");
            self.locationView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.locationField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [cell addSubview:self.locationView];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Starts", @"");
            if(self.selectedDate != nil)
            {
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                //[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
                [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];

                NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.selectedDate];

                cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;
            }
        }
        else if(indexPath.row == 1)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Ends", @"");
            if(self.selectedDate != nil)
            {
                NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                //[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
                [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

                NSString *stringFromDate = [formatter stringFromDate:self.selectedTime];

                cell.detailTextLabel.text = stringFromDate;
            }
        }

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Repeat",@"");
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Never", @"");
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 3)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Alert", @"");
            if(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ringtone"] isEqualToString:@""] && [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ringtone"] != nil)
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"ringtone"];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"None", @"");
            }
        }
    }
     else if (indexPath.section == 4)
     {
         if(indexPath.row == 0)
         {
             cell.textLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Calendar", @"");
             cell.detailTextLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Home", @"");
         }
     }
    else if(indexPath.section == 5 && indexPath.section != 0)
    {
        if(indexPath.row == 0)
        {
            self.urlView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            self.urlField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:128.0/255.0 green:128.0/255.0 blue:128.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [cell addSubview:self.urlView];
        }
    }
```

This is my code for method `cellforRowatIndexPath`
Any work around for that. I have debugged it and when it comes on the 5th section if statement it cannot find the section value and it jumps right into the if statement. and then the problem appears.
I have also checked that if it is nil or not but of no use.

Comment: you do realize that `indexPath.section = 5` is the 6th section since indexing starts at 0.

Comment: Pls show a screen shot of what is going wrong. Thx!

Comment: `else if(indexPath.section == 5 && indexPath.section != 0)` what is *that* supposed to mean?

Comment: it was to make sure that it only comes in the if statement if both the conditions are true.

Comment: It looks like from what you're doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath, that you have a fixed number of cells. If that's true, you probably should use a static table view, not a dynamic one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same reused cell (or the same batch of reused cells) for every type of cell, and adding subviews every time they are reused without then removing them. You should use a different cell identifier for each type of cell and only add subviews in the initialization.

edit: also, you should be adding subviews to the cell's contentView, not to it directly.

everywhere you put `[cell addSubview:whatever]`, replace with `[cell.contentView addSubview:whatever]`

based on the first comment on this answer by matt, here is a quick and dirty way of implementing this:

In order to remove all the subviews of a cell:

```
for (UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews) 
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Put that right before this line in your code

```
cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Keep in mind this solution will not be great in a table with many cells. You should really split up each cell into its own type where perhaps you keep track of any custom subviews by using their `tag` property.

Comment: Or just remove all the subviews every time before adding the subviews appropriate to this section/row. But I like your solution better, Dima; this is a good use of multiple identifiers.

Comment: That is simpler to code for sure, but there may be a performance hit if there are a lot of rows.

Comment: How to remove all the subviews before adding the others?

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. It worked great for me. Thanks a lot once again.